# Как создать тип в typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

Есть такой массив объектов

```
const arr = [
  { id: "0", name: "one" },
  { id: "1", name: "two" },
  { id: "2", name: "three" }
];
```

Мне нужно получить такой тип:

```
type Arr = {id: "0" | "1" | "2", name: "one" | "two" | "three"}[]
```

То есть каждому ключу присвоить все возможные значения, которые встречаются у этого ключа.
Проблема в том как это сделать не в ручную ?
Пробовал так:

```
type Arr = typeof arr;
```

Но это просто создает тип и помечает что значения ключей просто `string`, но мне нужно вместо этого перечислить все возможные значения, как это сделать ?

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgJwTAvDA2gKBjA3jASwBMAuGAIgAZyAaGMOAWwFMzzxnyYBfG7PQqQoBGWvSasKUAO4guvfvmJsATGIYs2UABYJmnHpgC68CDFCQoAbkyYoATwAOzGAEkAIgGVUMB85AAZvBIMMwAHlDMYERmAErMcETgADb2AIJIcPYAPLjKhGABzMgAGjwAfDAA-DBlZGDMAG7FNn4uAHJpALIAot5obYHByOGR0XEJSWCpGQhZuRqSBIXFtRXVa-VNLbZtMLM+uPw4+R6efDg4i2SdvZ6Y3OhGNkA

Comment: @Alexey Ten оформите как ответ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно так:

```
const arr = [
  { id: "0", name: "one" },
  { id: "1", name: "two" },
  { id: "2", name: "three" }
] as const;

type Arr = typeof arr extends ReadonlyArray<{id: infer X, name: infer Y }> ? { id: X, name: Y }[] : never;
```

[typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgJwTAvDA2gKBjA3jASwBMAuGAIgAZyAaGMOAWwFMzzxnyYBfG7PQqQoBGWvSasKUAO4guvfvmJsATGIYs2UABYJmnHpgC68CDFCQoAbkyYoATwAOzGAEEkqGA+cgAZvA9mAA8oZjAiMwAlZjgicAAbe3cEOHsAHlxlQjBfZmQADToNSQIcvJgATR4APhgAfgEswvFNSp50EzIwZgA3PJtMAHpBmBAAa0x45lhQ6DJkz3RMoQByShWiiTIVmRAVniMbYfoQWHHJ6a9maBV5jzQlwW2AZgBWDZbJHdl97kOgA)